# AngularJS - Can a module and a directive have the same name?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

For example:

```
angular.module('someName', []).

    directive('someName', function() {
        ...
    });
```

**Can this potentially cause problems in AngularJS? Should this be avoided?**

Comment: Not sure if it causes problems, but IMO it should probably be avoided on principal - one of those names probably isn't specific enough.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Nothing so far. Works fine, just don't want any surprises. As far as names goes there is a module for all code regarding to the virtual file room called fileRoom and in that module is all sorts of directives for fileRoom including the fileRoom itself.Long story short the names are precise and clean, and in context they are very clear, just worried about this.

Comment: I was wondering if there was anything concrete that would warrant against this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A module and a directive **can have the same name**. You could even include a service, factory, or provider with the same name as the module, but not the same name as one another.

The reason you can use the same name for the directive as the module is because the modules and their names are stored in one object and the directives and their names are stored in another object.

Comment: Exactly the kind of concrete answer I was looking for. Thanks.